# How to run a python script in background at specific time

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a desktop notifier in python and i want that it notify the user after the number of minutes he has entered in text widget i have made in root window but i want it reminds him at that time even if application isn't running. Can anyone help in my code.

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk,messagebox
from tkinter import font
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from plyer import notification
import time
#main window build up

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("720x500")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title('DESKTOP NOTIFIER')

#defining commands for widgets

def notifiy():
    title1=entry1.get(1.0,END)
    message1=entry2.get(1.0,END)
    time1=entry3.get(1.0,END)
    if title1 == '\n' or message1 == '\n' or time1 == '\n' :
        messagebox.showerror('Alert','All fields are not filled')
    else:

        notification.notify(
            title = f'{title1}',
            message = f'{message1}',
            app_icon = 'favicon (1).ico',
            timeout = 15,
        )
        


#making widgets
label0=Label(root,text='DESKTOP NOTIFIER',font=('lemonmilk',20)).place(x=250,y=20)
label3=Label(root,text='min',font=('lemonmilk 15')).place(x=275,y=310)


#entry1
entry1=Text(root,width=55,height=2)
entry1.place(x=200,y=130)
label1=Label(root,text='TITLE: ',font=('lemonmilk',15)).place(x=120,y=133)



#entry2
entry2=Text(root,width=55,height=5)
entry2.place(x=200,y=195)
label2=Label(root,text='DESCRIPITION: ',font=('lemonmilk',15)).place(x=35,y=200)



#entry3
entry3=Text(root,width=6,height=1,font=('lemonmilk'))
entry3.place(x=200,y=310)
label33=Label(root,text=' SET TIME: ',font=('lemonmilk',15)).place(x=70,y=310)


#buttons
button1=Button(root,text='NOTIFY ME!',width=15,height=4,font=('lemonmilk 13         bold'),command=notifiy).place(x=460,y=370)
button2=Button(root,text='QUIT APPLICATION',width=20,height=4,font=('lemonmilk 13     bold'),command=root.destroy).place(x=150,y=370)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can't, but you can use external tools like cron jobs to run the script at certain times

Comment: the header of this question is how to run a script in specific time, but in your description you are asking "to run the program every time the user have made a text input with some minutes of delay"? what are you trying to achive?